# Boost file blocking use of SHGetKnownFolderPath

Tags: c++, boost, header-files

The issue I'm having is that I am trying to create a function that will retrieve the file path to the desktop dynamically and return it as a string, the function works because I used it in another program. However the new program I'm trying to use it in also uses "boost/asio.hpp", when I include this file then VisualStudio tells me that `SHGetKnownFolderPath` is undefined but if I take out the `#include<boost/asio.hpp>` then it throws errors because of the code that requires it.

Im not sure at all what to add subtract or change to get this to work, there's really no straight answer out there that I've found, Thanks.

**EDIT:** Here is the source file includes

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>
#include "INSData.pb.h"
#include "Header.h"
#include "shellapi.h"
#include "SQLHeader.h"
```

Here is the Header.h Includes

```
#include <shlobj.h>//for knownFolder
#include <winerror.h> //for HRESULT
#include <comutil.h> //for _bstr_t (used in the string conversion)
#include "fstream"
#include <regex>
#include "MGS/GoogleEarth/KmlNodes.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "comsuppw")
```

Comment: include Shlobj.h file

Comment: i have that file included in another header file that is declared after the boost files. i will show you include statements

Comment: Taking a guess here, does boost asio define windows version like `WINVER` and/or `_WIN32_WINNT`, and/or are you not targeting Vista and above using these macro's, which would cause the shlobj.h header to not including new functionality?

Comment: Im not entirely sure actually if i open that asio file its just a huge list of other includes, I am using this on Vista or higher however

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up going an alternate route. Just moved the definition of the functions that needed the conflicting file to another .cpp file and declared them in a .h file that both .cpp files have access to.